# Происхождение слова "пушка"

Tags: этимология

Пушки в России и, следовательно, в русском языке появились сравнительно недавно. И вот интересно, как было придумано само слово "пушка"? Или оно заимствованное?

Answer (score 4):

Слово-путешественник. Начало его истории, видимо, в греческом "пюксис" (и
латинском "буксис") - втулка из очень прочного дерева самшита, буксуса. В
древненемецком языке из "буксис" получилось "Buhsa" - "трубка" (стоит
вспомнить, что древнейшие орудия нередко бывали деревянными; их оковывали
обручами), а из него чешское "puszka" - "ружье" и польское "puszka" -
"жестянка" (раньше и "ружье"). Мы, вероятно, уже очень давно позаимствовали
польское слово, но придали ему несколько иное значение - не "ружье", а
"орудие".

По Л. Успенскому.

Comment: Букс

букс стар. буксбом, во времена Петра I; см. Смирнов 68. Через нем. Buchsbaum из лат. buxus "букс, самшит"; см. Горяев, ЭС 32. Ср. также букшпан. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973


вообще -то немецкий хоть чуть чуть знать надо.
по корням Buchsbaum бумага+дерево
Самши́т (лат. Búxus) — род растений семейства Самшитовые, медленнорастущие вечнозелёные кустарники и деревца, вырастающие до высоты 2—12 м (изредка 15 м).
В германии не растет и из него бумагу не делали.
Busch-букса, куст---вот тогда и будет самшит

Answer (score -2):

По болгарски пушить дымить пушка при выстреле много дыма

Comment: Комментарий не надо выдавать за Ответ.